# I need to do a membrane pcb for a keyboard or a flexible PCB like a membrane PCB

Tags: pcb, button, keyboard, flexible, flex

I need to design a membrane PCB for a keyboard and/or flexible double sided PCB that works like a membrane PCB.  My problem here is that I don't know how to do the buttons, with one contact of the button in one layer and the other contact in another layer.  Similar to what can be seen in this image:

[image: Example PCB]

Also: Which software is better for doing this, Proteus or Altium?

Comment: Are you planning to use printed carbon or ? Why reinvent the button keyboard?!what MTBF spec do you need?

Comment: I'm not planning to reinvent the button keyboard, is my first keyboard design and I see that one contact of the button is in one layer and the other contact is in the other layer, in fact, the keyboard in the layer is the one that I need to replace. I'm asking for help on how to make the buttons because I don´t know how and also I don't have the original design so I must do the design myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: material compatibility to prevent oxidation is need such as gold alloy finish  (ENIG)

Comment: ok, thank you, so may be membrane would be the one I think

Comment: so why can you not buy a standard membrane keypad? instead reinventing the problems to solve "inventing" your first design

Answer (score 1):

With custom PCB's like flex or membrane usually the manufacturer will take gerbers, so it doesn't matter what software you use. But the manufacturer will have different requirements than a normal PCB. Pick a manufacturer, then work with them on how to draw up the stackup, minimum trace and contact requirements.

Altium does have the ability to create layers\stackup for flex circuits.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, could you give me some advices on how to make the buttons?. I don't have the original design so I have to do it myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Who is your manufacturer?

Comment: Well, I've only talked with PCBway but I haven't send the gerber file yet, I'm  currently doing the design by simply drawing tracks and about to finish it